# InnoSetup Dynamic ComboBox, check which item is selected and execute program

Tags: select, dynamic, combobox, inno-setup

In InnoSetup I want to disply a ComboBox on the Finished Page which shows the Components that were installed.
You can choose "None" or any of the installed Components and start the associated program when clicking on finish.

This is my code so far:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  NewComboBox1: TNewComboBox;
begin
  if (CurPageID = wpFinished) then begin
  NewComboBox1 := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewComboBox1 do begin
    Parent := WizardForm.FinishedPage;
    Left := ScaleX(256);
    Top := ScaleY(208);
    Width := ScaleX(145);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    ItemIndex := 0;
    Style := csDropDownList;
    Items.Add('None');
    if IsComponentSelected('1') then
    Items.Add('Component 1');
    if IsComponentSelected('2') then
    Items.Add('Component 2');
    if IsComponentSelected('3') then
    Items.Add('Component 3');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

First I want to set "None" as automatically selected. when the page is shown. I have looked up many Pascal forums but none of the solutions worked, like NewComboBox1.ItemSelected=0 (or similar, don't remember correctly...). So how do I achieve this?

Then I don't know how to make a program start when clicking on Finish. I thought

```
function NextButtonClick
```

might help but then no Next button worked in the setup.

Maybe there is also a problem because the list is created depending on which Components were selected, so item 1 is not Component 1, if Component 1 was not selected but Component 2 for instance.

I thought one might solve this by making the items invisible instead of not creating them at all.

I looked in the Support Classes Reference in the IS help file but didn't find anything that would help me.

I am looking forward to your answers!

Comment: You're setting the `ItemIndex` too early. You need to feed the combo box and after that set the item index. Setting `ItemIndex` silently fail in your current code since there's no item with index 0 yet.

Comment: Alright, I set ItemIndex at the end and now None is shown automatically! Thanks for this! Now I only need to know how to get the value of the chosen item...

Comment: You're not going to get the *value*, you want to open the file which is *behind* the component selected in combo box, don't you ?

Comment: You should really add the controls in the `InitializeWizard()` event function. You can then (clear and) add any items needed and select the default in `CurPageChanged(wpFinished)`.

Comment: Yes, with every component an .exe-file gets installed. With the ComboBox I want to give the user the option to start one of the installed .exe-files.

Comment: So, you're showing the name of the *.exe file in that combo box ? And if so, are all of those components installed in one directory ? If you're showing component descriptions (it seems you're doing so in your code example), then it's quite difficult to do this automatically - in this case would be easier to store the name of the file manually to some collection.

Comment: Yes, I'm showing the component descriptions since it looks better and the .exe-files have to be run with certain parameters, otherwise the programs won't work.

Comment: Will your component list be just a simple one level list of all available applications and nothing more ?

Comment: One level list? Well, the list should only contain the names of the installed applications, yes. It is only meant to show the user which applpications he can start.

Comment: I meant component list, not that final combo box. I see that the combo box should be filled with installed components. The component list may have multiple levels and contain e.g. item `Windows Applications` with two subitems `Calculator` and `Solitaire`. You can also have a component list containing e.g. `Help files` which you don't want to include to the final combo box. I'd like to know if your component list will contain only applications that you want to populate to that combo box if user selects them in comp. list.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Yes, every selected item in the component list is meant to be shown in the combobox as well, no exceptions. And there are no subcomponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple way to do this due to a lack of missing access to the file name and destination directory which the component is binded to. Even `TSetupComponentEntry` internal record doesn't contain this information, but even if would, you won't be able to access it. So, the following script uses its own separate array which contains the component/file linkage needed for this task:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Components]
Name: "program_32"; Description: "Program 32-bit"
Name: "program_x64"; Description: "Program 64-bit"
Name: "program_ia64"; Description: "Program IA 64-bit"

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program_32
Source: "MyProg-x64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program_x64
Source: "MyProg-IA64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program_ia64

[Code]
type
  TFileData = record
    Component: string;
    Description: string;
    FileName: string;
    Parameters: string;
  end;  
var  
  ComponentCombo: TNewComboBox;
  ComponentArray: array of TFileData;
  SelectionArray: array of TFileData;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // this is a weakness of this solution - you need to fill the array
  // of components that can be added to the final combo box when they
  // are selected on component selection page. This is needed because
  // you can't get neither file name nor destination directory of the
  // file for the component from script. As first, set how many items
  // you want to add to your component array storage
  SetArrayLength(ComponentArray, 2);
  // the Component member must match to the "Name" parameter from the
  // [Components] section item since it's used in IsComponentSelected
  // function call
  ComponentArray[0].Component := 'program_32';
  // the Description member is the text displayed in the combo item
  ComponentArray[0].Description := 'Program 32-bit';
  // the FileName member is the name of the file including path. This
  // member may contain InnoSetup constants
  ComponentArray[0].FileName := '{app}/MyProg.exe';
  // the Parameters member contains execution parameters
  ComponentArray[0].Parameters := '-a';
  // this is the second item that can be added to the combo box, note
  // that the program_ia64 component is not added to this array, what
  // means, that it cannot be added to the "run" combo box. It's such
  // kind of a filter for components like help files etc.
  ComponentArray[1].Component := 'program_x64';
  ComponentArray[1].Description := 'Program 64-bit';
  ComponentArray[1].FileName := '{app}/MyProg-x64.exe';
  ComponentArray[1].Parameters := '-b';
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (CurPageID = wpFinished) then
  begin
    ComponentCombo := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
    ComponentCombo.Parent := WizardForm.FinishedPage;
    ComponentCombo.Left := ScaleX(256);
    ComponentCombo.Top := ScaleY(208);
    ComponentCombo.Width := ScaleX(145);
    ComponentCombo.Height := ScaleY(21);
    ComponentCombo.Style := csDropDownList;

    ComponentCombo.Items.Add('None');
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(ComponentArray) - 1 do
      if IsComponentSelected(ComponentArray[I].Component) then
      begin
        ComponentCombo.Items.Add(ComponentArray[I].Description);
        SetArrayLength(SelectionArray, GetArrayLength(SelectionArray) + 1);
        SelectionArray[High(SelectionArray)] := ComponentArray[I];
      end;      
    ComponentCombo.ItemIndex := 0;
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  FileData: TFileData;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (CurPageID = wpFinished) and (ComponentCombo.ItemIndex > 0) then
  begin
    FileData := SelectionArray[ComponentCombo.ItemIndex - 1];
    Exec(ExpandConstant(FileData.FileName), FileData.Parameters, '', SW_SHOW,
      ewNoWait, ResultCode);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your efforts! I just wanted to try it but got an error: 
Line 185: 
Column 24:
Unknown identifier 'High' .... It's in the line "SelectionArray[High(SelectionArray)] := ComponentArray[I];"

Comment: You're welcome! I've tested this script in Unicode InnoSetup 5.5.1, what should be the most recent version at this time, so maybe it's not in some older versions.

Comment: There is even a newer version, 5.5.2, but I had the non-unicode version... I installed IS-Unicode and then it worked! Thank you again!

Comment: D'oh, I'm 3 days late with the most recent version :-) I have to upgrade now!

Comment: If `High(x)` is unavailable it can be replaced with `GetArrayLength(x)-1`.  (Just in case someone wants to use this code without switching to Unicode.)

Comment: @Miral, I'm wondering why there's this difference between Unicode and ANSI versions. Strange...

Comment: The Unicode version is built using a more recent version of Delphi.  (IIRC it's Delphi 2007 for Unicode and Delphi 2 for ANSI, for reasons of reducing overhead size.)  Not sure how/why that would affect the scripting language though -- but `High` isn't one of the documented support functions, so it's YMMV I guess.